# how to check if a table row only have 1 visible table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say that I have a table with id "unique" and that i have executed

```
$('.8').hide();
$('.3').hide();
```

Now I only want to show the row with 1 visible collumn and hide the rest, I.E I want to hide all rows except the first one (Still having the second and third collumn hidden), how can I check if a table row have more than 1 visible collumn?

```
<table id="unique">
<tr class = "opponent4 opponent3 opponent5">
<td class="1">1</td>
<td class="3">3</td>
<td class="8">8</td>
</tr>
<tr class = "opponent7 opponent3 opponent9">
<td class="1">1</td>
<td class="1">1</td>
<td class="8">8</td>
</tr>
<tr class = "opponent1 opponent3 opponent4">
<td class="1">1</td>
<td class="2">2</td>
<td class="8">8</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get an array of TRs. Filter out ones that contain 1 visible TD. Hide the rest.

```
$("#unique tr").filter(function() { return $(this).find("td:visible").length != 1}).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each($('unique tr'), function() { //Loop through rows
  if ($(this).children('td:visible').length > 1) { //If this row has more than one visible column
    $(this).hide(); //hide this row
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If this is a critical part of your program, I'd save something like this to a function.

```
$.fn.multipleColumnRows = function() {
  var result = [];
  $.each($(this).children('tr'), function() { 
      if ($(this).children('td:visible').length > 1) {
        result.push($(this));
      }
   }
   return result;
}

$('#unique').multipleColumnRows.hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr', '#unique').each(function(i,t){
if('td:visible', $(t)).length == 1)
$(t).show();
Else $(t).hide();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $.each($(".8"), function() { 
        if (i === 0) { 
            i++;
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Then do that for the other ones!  Dont forget to reset i to 0

Comment: @downvoter feedback please.  I do not mind the downvote but explain to me why and ill be happy.  kthx

Comment: You are looping through the columns, not the rows. Plus, your code has to be repeated for any possible class of column. It's neither dynamic nor DRY. Nothing personal, it just simply does not work.

Comment: Although rereading, I believe you misunderstood the question. He has already hidden the 2nd and 3rd columns in distinct rows. He want to hide the ROWS that show more than one column. Also, order was not specified.

Comment: yeah, i misread it.  My bad.  Sorry everyone do not look at my stuff.  For some odd reason with his example i just assumed he wanted to hide the columns with the repeating classes in them.  Not sure why, i read it to fast probably.